# Prove that this integral with exponent with whole part is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polar-coordinates

How can i prove that this integral is convergent?

$$ \int_{\vert\xi\vert\geq 1} \vert\xi\vert ^{-2\left[ \frac{n}{2}\right] -2} d\xi $$

I thought to use polar coordinates but i don't know how to work with $ \left[ \frac{n}{2}\right] $.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $n$? Is it a positive integer? You need to specify those things, because if $n<-1$, then there could be trouble

Comment: Yes, n is a positive integer, sorry.